# What is the format for “Modulhandbuch” (course description) of previous degrees when applying for MS in German universities?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, germany

My bachelor’s degree is in Electronics and Communication Engineering.  I will be applying as **non-EU applicant**  for an M.Sc. in electrical engineering and information technology (“Elektrotechnik und Informationstechnik”) at German Universities.

For application, I need to upload the “Modulhandbuch” of my previous bachelor’s degree to prove my degree equivalence with German B.Sc. degree in electrical engineering. Karlsruhe Institute of Technology and University of Stuttgart are asking for this Modulhandbuch.

---

**Example 1** from [Admission Requirement (Zugangsvoraussetzungen) at KIT](https://www.sle.kit.edu/english/vorstudium/master-electrical-engineering-information-technology.php):

> Admission to the degree program requires successful completion of a degree program resembling the bachelor's degree program in Electrical Engineering and Information Technology at KIT in content and volume. The following must be part of the program:
> advanced mathematics
> fundamentals of eletrical engineering (e.g. "linear eletrical networks", "electromagnetic fields", "electromagnetic waves", "electronic circuit")
> systems engineering (e.g. "system dynamics and control systems engineering", "signals and system")
> digital and information technology

**Example 2** from University of Stuttgart [LINK](https://www.uni-stuttgart.de/studium/bewerbung/international-degree/bewerbung/), under “Nicht-EU-Bürgerinnen” (non-EU citizens):

> Zusätzlich für Bewerbungen in Masterstudiengänge:
>
> - Je nach Fach gibt es möglicherweise Ergänzungsanträge, die Sie der Bewerbung unbedingt beilegen sollten. Sie finden diese auf der Seite Auswahlkriterien und Zulassungsordnungen Master-Studiengänge
> - Beschreibung der Studieninhalte Ihres abgeschlossenen Bachelor-Studiengangs

English version:

> Additional documentation for applicants to Master's study programs:
>
> - Depending on the subject, there may be supplementary amendments that you should attach to the application. You can find this on the page: Selection criteria and admission statutes for Master's study programs
> - Description of the contents of your completed Bachelor's study program

---

##### Problem

This Modulhandbuch is known as *course curriculum* or *course description* in my home country. In my case, the course-curriculum booklet that I collected from my previous university is hundred pages long with several elective subjects of multiple specializations.

##### Question

1. Should I upload the entire scanned booklet?
2. Should I include only the specific pages that are covered (main subjects + elective subjects that I've taken) as per my transcript or mark sheets?
3. In case of KIT, should I include only the specific pages as asked by the admission committee?
4. Any further suggestions and advice are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I switched my BA, I had to provide the new university with the "Studienordnung" (the whole thing, a 60+ page document) of my previous studies, so they could assess which courses from the first uni that I already completed could count towards my switched BA topic. This was when switching from a German uni to another German one, not even from one outside of Germany or the EU.

So I suggest you send in the whole document. After all, in form of a PDF it will not be a huge file size. Combined with the transcript of which courses you actually took, they can figure out themselves which of the info in the document is relevant. If you just send in an excerpt, chances are that they will later ask you for the whole document anyway, to ensure you didn't omit crucial information (not necessarily out of malice, but because you don't really know whats relevant for them).

Comment: As a German professor working in this area and being occasionally tasked to look through such files, I second this. Send all potentially relevant document(s), we can quickly find the relevant parts.